# Elixir: What is the equivalent of a for each within a for each?

Tags: elixir

Given the following list of maps:

```
ball_prop_list = 
[
  %{"id" => "cue", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => -15.0, "z" => 0.0},
  %{"id" => "ball_1", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 15.0, "z" => 0.0},
  %{"id" => "ball_2", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.0, "z" => 1.1},
  %{"id" => "ball_3", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.0, "z" => -1.1}
]
```

How do I run through each item, and then compare it to every item in the list (ignoring itself)?

The original code is in C#, and would essentially be:

```
foreach (bodyA in objectList) {
    foreach (bodyB in objectList) {
        if (bodyA == bodyB) {
            continue;
        }    
        // Do other stuff here
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
Enum.map(ball_prop_list , fn
    body_a ->
        Enum.map(ball_prop_list , fn body_b -> 
            if body_a["id"] != body_b["id"] do
                Sys.Log.debug("#{body_a["id"]} (A) vs #{body_a["id"]} (B)")
                # Compute other stuff here
            end
        end)
end)
```

But I don't think it's working as expected, as this is what the logs look like, repeatedly:

[image]

I was expecting some `cue (A) vs ball_1 (B)` etc., but it wasn't happening; and of course, it's comparing A to A, by the looks of things. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: I think you might be able to simplify your question.  Have you looked at list (and map) comprehensions?  https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html Those are the recommended way of calculating things like cartesian products.

Comment: @Everett, thanks I am currently looking into this, but unfortunately, the real answer is much more embarrassing...

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation of the original code would have been

```elixir
Enum.each(ball_prop_list, fn body_a ->
  Enum.each(ball_prop_list, fn
    ^body_a -> :ok
    body_b -> # Do other stuff here
  end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere, my approach would have worked; it was simply a display issue:

```
Sys.Log.debug("#{body_a["id"]} (A) vs #{body_a["id"]} (B)")
```

Should be:

```
Sys.Log.debug("#{body_a["id"]} (A) vs #{body_b["id"]} (B)")
```

Although as pointed out by Everett in the comment above, the recommended way of doing this would be using comprehension, which would look something like this:

```
for body_a <- ball_prop_list,                 # for clause 1, declares variable body_a
    body_b <- ball_prop_list -- [body_a],     # for clause 2, declares variable body_b
    isCollisionDetected(body_a, body_b), do:  # test clause, only true results pass
    {:collision, a, b}                        # "Return statement": this is how we format passing results
```

The return statement isn't quite formatted as I'd want it to be (still working on that) as it would result in this:

```
[{:collision, obj5, obj99}, {:collision, obj1, obj7} ...]
# Where each obj is a map from ball_prop_list
```

but that's another problem for another time, and this should answer the question "what is the equivalent of a for each within a for each".

Comment: Good catch!  Is there a reason you're using `Sys.Log.debug` instead of `Logger.debug` ?

Comment: @Everett, it's unsaid in the question, but I am using a proprietary Server Development Environment that merely uses Elixir for the code base, and the documentation of said SDE recommends we use `Sys.Log.debug`. I haven't tried `Logger.debug` myself (or the other suggested `IO.debug` if I'm not mistaken), but I am unfortunately dealing with people who would rather we "stick to the documentation", however incomplete or obsolete it may be.

Comment: `for body_a <- ball_prop_list, body_b <- ball_prop_list -- [body_a]` is a very wrong approach, because it iterates the list to remove the item and then produces the result and then iterates it again. The correct one would be `for body_a <- ball_prop_list, body_b <- ball_prop_list, body_a != body_b`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, thanks for catch, I just tested it out and seems to work.